# Error on boot after repair disk

Tags: boot, command-line

My computer running `ubuntu 14.04Lts` had no problems until it wouldn't start anymore due to an error. I applied the `ubuntu repair disk` and it would boot again though it gives these errors every boot.

`error: sis630 Compatible bus not detected, mo`

`error: emask exception`

`failed command SET FEATURES`

I don't remember correctly but there was more, it could slightly differ.

Also something like this pops up:

`System problem detected`

`Do you want to report the problem now?`

It does this randomly, I'd say `2/5 times on boot`, and it does it `twice`. One in the `upper left` and one in the `middle`.

I don't notice anything strange to the computer. I can't figure out what this means.

Answer (score 0):

What sort of error did you get originally?

The new message is referring to the motherboard graphics chipset, see [the makers site](http://w3.sis.com/support/linux_old.htm) - you probably need a driver, unless it was a hardware fault in the first place? It's probably just running on a default driver now & complaining about it.

If you go through the initial steps to "report the error" you can see some detail about what that error actually is, which may be helpful.

Comment: I don't remember the error before the repair disk. But it can very well be hardware related, it's an older computer